# Number of Wordpress pages cause PHP memory limit crash

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, limit, wpallimport

I plan to import 30000 URLs (big site about food, calories and other nutrient information) to wordpress using a plugin called WP All Import. It works fine and I splitted the XML files to 1000 pages per file. The import runs super fast (I have a great server with 7 cores and lots of RAM).

I increased the PHP memory limit to 1024 MB and 1000 pages are imported in 4 minutes. However, the bigger the number of pages (after 11000 there was the first critical error) the more likely was my PHP memory limit reached although the site was just in idle mode (imports were successfully finished and I clicked through the dashboard).

Just when I log into my wordpress dashboard and click on "pages" the memory limit all of a sudden bounces from 4 out of 1024MB (dashboard page) to 1024/1024 ("pages" page) and the wordpress critical error appears.

Since I know many wordpress sites that are very big (50000 URLs / products and more) I'm sure this has to be solved in some way... I tried deactivating all the plugins and used the wordpress standard theme but still no luck.

Also I experimented with the CRON jobs and my hoster was super helpful - but still no luck...

So how come the memory limit suddenly "fills" when the page / dashboard is in idle mode?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have permission to SSH into your server and run a direct SQL statement? Or able to run a SQL statement wthin phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes I do - but I need to run the Import Plugin within wordpress - otherwise the site design etc. will be messed up

Comment: I believe I misunderstood, you are able to import the pages but running the site post-import is the issue?

Comment: Exactly. The more pages I import, the more PHP Memory is used although there is no traffic at all yet. When I exceed the limit of 11000 (rough estimate) pages, the whole thing crashes and thats it. So is it really normal that wordpress is limited to approx. 10000 pages? My server is huge and the Memory Limit is at 1024.

Comment: Since you're able to access the site files and mysql database you will be able to restore the site as it was/is. All the information you are concerned about is contained within the database and/or php/html/js/css files. So restoring a complete backup of the database and files of the website will do it - not via any plugin, just on the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable without any plugin. Any WordPress site may be restored in essentially two steps.

- Restore web files.
- Restore database.
- Adjust any configuration necessary so WP may connect to the database (wp-config.php).

**Source server**

Start by creating an archive of the previous site's files (zip,tar,etc.).

```
$ tar caf archive-name.tar.gz /path/to/wordpress/site
```

Next a complete export of the WordPress database.

```
$ mysqldump -u [user name] –p [password] [options] [database_name] [tablename] > [dumpfilename.sql]
```

If using phpmyadmin [documentation is found here.](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/docs/)

**Destination Server**

Then on the destination server extract the files into the web root and restore the MySQL database. Then you will have to ensure some configuration within wp-config.php so the database is accessible.

Finally, restart your web and database services and load up the site. Everything should be as it was.